# Exporting XAML drawing to image file

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

I'm new to WPF. The problem is to export an image which is a simple UI button icon from a WPF project. I tried to locate the image in solution folders. Then I managed to figure out that it doesn't exist at all it's merely a geometry drawing in XAML!!! The question is there any tool for extracting such graphics to png file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export XAML as image using [Expression Design](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/design_overview.aspx).

See following links for details:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/popflygamecreator/thread/a9fade6d-ec35-454e-b404-45115a9939aa
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294508(v=expression.40).aspx

And also check this project:

- http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2008/10/10/converting-and-customizing-xaml-to-png-with-server-side-wpf.aspx

XamlToPngConverter class is what you need.

Comment: Thank you! I had to find it myself :)

Comment: You are welcome @Andrey, I've added another interesting project, you should take a look.